# Solution of non linear second order differential equation is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on the problem:

Prove that, for any $c \in [0, 1),$ the solution $t \mapsto x_c(t)$ of the problem
$$\begin{cases} 
 \ddot x + (1+c^2)x - 2c^3x^3 = 0  \\  
 x(0)=0 \\  
\dot x(0)=1  
 \end{cases}$$
is periodic. What about $c=1$?

My background on ode is the basic theory studied in the first courses of calculus.

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions.

Comment: For what it's worth, your DE can be reduced to the first order IVP $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{c^3x^4-(1+c^2)x^2+1}, \text{ }x(0)=0$$ using the conventional substitution $u=\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: @Jean L. The last term should be $-\tfrac{c^3}{2}x^4$.

Comment: I think that we don't have to solve this equation. we only need, by a qualitative study, to prove that there exists a $T > 0$ such that $x(t) = 0$ and $x'(T) = 1$. In that case $y = x(t + T)$ will be a solution of the same problem and by uniqueness of the solution $x(t) = y(t) = x(t + T)$  and we deduce that $x$ is periodic.

Comment: @Jean L. Thank you, I understand your advice. So to conclude I have to show that the contour line that crosses the point (0,1) is "circle-like" and that the solution spins on this circle (i.e. It doesn't stop at the points (1,0) and (-1,0)), correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the second order equation by $\dot{x}$ an integrating we get that
$$\frac12(\dot{x})^2+\frac{1+c^2}{2}x^2-\frac{c^3}{2}x^4=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2(0)+\frac{1+c^2}{2}x^2(0)-\frac{c^3}{2}x^4(0)$$
The solution to the initial value problem satisfies
$$\frac12(\dot{x})^2+\frac12(1+c^2)x^2-\frac12c^3x^4=\frac12$$
The function
\begin{align}
H(x,y)=\frac12 y^2+\frac12(1+c^2)x^2-\frac12c^3x^4\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}$$
has the property that if $x(t)$ is a solution to the second order equation with initial conditions $(x(0),\cdot{x}(0))$, then $\partial_f H(x(t),\dot{x}(t))=0$.

Setting $y=\dot{x}$, we can turn the  second order differential equation in the OP to the following 2-dimentional first order differential equation
$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{y}
\end{pmatrix} &=\begin{pmatrix} y\\ -(1+c^2)x+2c^3x^3\end{pmatrix}=f_c(x,y)\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
The initial conditions of interest then become
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\ y_0\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

The system \eqref{one} has three steady state solutions   $\mathbf{p}_0:=\mathbf{0}=[0,0]^\intercal$, $\mathbf{p}_{\pm}:=\Big[\pm\sqrt{\tfrac{1+c^2}{2c^3}},0\Big]^\intercal$. Assuming $c>0$, the point $\mathbf{0}$ corresponds to a "center" in that  the eigenvalues of $Ff(\mathbf{0})$, $\pm i\sqrt{1+c^2}$, are imaginary; the points $\mathbf{p}_{\pm}$ corresponds to saddle points as the eigenvalues of $Df(\mathbf{p}_{\pm})$, $\sqrt{2(1+c^2)}$ and $-\sqrt{2(1+c^2)}$ in both cases, are real and differ in sign.

This system has a first integral $H(x,y)$ given by \eqref{zero}
Futhermore, the system is Hamiltonian since
$$\dot{y}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x},\qquad \dot{x}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}$$

The Hessian of $H$ is given by
$$D^2H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 1+c^2-6c^3x^2 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\operatorname{det}H(\mathbf{p}_0)=1+c^2\neq0$ and so, $H$ is perserves sign in a neighborhood $B(\mathbf{0},r)$, i.e. $H(\mathbf{p})>0$ for all $p\in B(\mathbf{0},r)\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$. This means that all solutions with initial conditions closed enough to $\mathbf{0}$ are periodic.

We now show that if $0<c<1$, then the solution $\mathbf{p}(t;(0,1))=[x(t),y(t)]^\intercal$ that satisfies the initial condition $(x(0),y_=(0))=(0,1)$ is in fact periodic. Notice that
$$H(\mathbf{p}(t))=\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}(1+c^2)x^2-\frac12c^3x^4=\frac12$$
The point $(x_-,0)$ where
$$x_-=\sqrt{\frac{1+c^2-\sqrt{(1+c^2)^2-4c^3}}{2c^3}}$$
is in the level curve $H(x,y)=\frac12$ and  $(x_-,0)\notin\{\mathbf{p}_+,\mathbf{p}_-,\mathbf{0}\}$ and $0<x_-<\sqrt{\frac{1+c^2}{2c^3}}$ which means that the solution to the system \eqref{zero} that passes through either the point $(x_-,0)$ is periodic.

There are two separatrices (one point from $\mathbf{p}_-$ to $\mathbf{p}_+$ and the other going from $\mathbf{p}_+$ to $\mathbf{p}_-$. These separatrices intersect the axis $x=0$ at points $(\pm a, 0)$. Any point in the level curve
$$H(x,y)=H(\mathbf{p}_+)=H(\mathbf{p}_-)=\frac{1}{8}\frac{(1+c^2)^2}{c^3}$$
that is not in $\{\mathbf{p}_-,\mathbf{p}_+\}$ is in either of the separatrices.

The map $y\mapsto H(0,y)$, $y\geq0$ is strictly monotone increasing. Since $H(\mathbf{p}_{\pm})=H(a,0)=\frac{1}{8}\frac{(1+c^2)^2}{c^3}>\frac12$, it follows that $(0,1)$ is in the orbit of the periodic solution that passes through $(x_-,0)$.

Here is an example of the contours of $H$ around $\mathbf{0}$ for $c=.6$

[image]

---

When $c=1$, the point $(0,1)$ is in the one of the separatrices that joint the saddle points $\mathbf{p}_+=(1,0)$ and $\mathbf{p}_-=(-1,0)$. Henc, in this case the solution $\mathbf{p}(t;(0,1))$ to system \eqref{one} that passes through $(0,1)$ is not a periodic solution.